# Django Login system breaks the javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-templates

So I am creating a Django application and so far I have a nice template using HTML, CSS, and Javascript, however once I implemented an authentication system the javascript only works when a user is logged in but stops working once they are logged out. Before I implemented the login system, the javascript used `localStorage` in order to store theme preferences and it worked perfectly but now the javascript only works if a user is currently logged in, so I decided to try to use cookies in order to store a user's theme preferences but that also only works once user is logged in. I'm not sure how to proceed any help is much appreciated.

Here is the javascript file using `localStorage`

```
const body = document.body;
const themeToggleBtn = selectElement('#theme-toggle-btn');
const currentTheme = getCookie('currentTheme');

// Check to see if there is a theme preference in the cookie, if so add the light theme to the body
if (currentTheme) {
    body.classList.add('light-theme');
}

themeToggleBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    // Add light theme on click
    body.classList.toggle('light-theme');

    // If the body has the class of light theme then add it to cookie with a longer expiration time, if not remove it
    if (body.classList.contains('light-theme')) {
        setCookie('currentTheme', 'themeActive', 365);
    } else {
        setCookie('currentTheme', '', -1);
    }
});

function setCookie(name, value, days) {
    let expires = '';
    if (days) {
        const date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "")  + expires + "; path=/";
}

function getCookie(name) {
    const nameEQ = name + "=";
    const ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(let i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        let c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here is the modified code using Cookies

```
// Grab elements
const selectElement = (selector) => {
    const element = document.querySelector(selector);
    if(element) return element;
    throw new Error(`Something went wrong! Make sure that ${selector} exists/is typed correctly.`);  
};

//Nav styles on scroll
const scrollHeader = () => {
    const navbarElement = selectElement('#header');
    if (navbarElement) {
        if (this.scrollY >= 15) {
            navbarElement.classList.add('activated');
        } else {
            navbarElement.classList.remove('activated');
        }
    }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollHeader);

// Open menu & search pop-up
const menuToggleIcon = selectElement('#menu-toggle-icon');
const formOpenBtn = selectElement('#search-icon');
const formCloseBtn = selectElement('#form-close-btn');
const searchContainer = selectElement('#search-form-container');

const toggleMenu = () => {
    const mobileMenu = selectElement('#menu');
    if (mobileMenu) {
        mobileMenu.classList.toggle('activated');
        menuToggleIcon.classList.toggle('activated');
    }
}

menuToggleIcon.addEventListener('click', toggleMenu);

// Open/Close search form popup
const toggleSearchForm = () => {
    const searchContainer = selectElement('#search-form-container');
    if (searchContainer) {
        searchContainer.classList.toggle('activated');
    }
}

formOpenBtn.addEventListener('click', () => searchContainer.classList.add('activated'));
formCloseBtn.addEventListener('click', () => searchContainer.classList.remove('activated'));
// -- Close the search form popup on ESC keypress
window.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
    const searchContainer = selectElement('#search-form-container');
    if (searchContainer && event.key === 'Escape') {
        searchContainer.classList.remove('activated');
    }
});

const body = document.body;
const themeToggleBtn = selectElement('#theme-toggle-btn');
const currentTheme = getCookie('currentTheme');

// Check to see if there is a theme preference in the cookie, if so add the light theme to the body
if (currentTheme) {
    body.classList.add('light-theme');
}

themeToggleBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    // Add light theme on click
    body.classList.toggle('light-theme');

    // If the body has the class of light theme then add it to cookie with a longer expiration time, if not remove it
    if (body.classList.contains('light-theme')) {
        setCookie('currentTheme', 'themeActive', 365);
    } else {
        setCookie('currentTheme', '', -1);
    }
});

function setCookie(name, value, days) {
    let expires = '';
    if (days) {
        const date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "")  + expires + "; path=/";
}

function getCookie(name) {
    const nameEQ = name + "=";
    const ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(let i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        let c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

// Swiper
const swiper = new Swiper(".swiper", {
    // How many slides to show
    slidesPerView: 1,
    // How much space between slides
    spaceBetween: 20,
    // Make the next and previous buttons work
    navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },
    // Make the pagination indicators work
    pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination'
    },
    //Responsive breakpoints for how many slides to show at that view
    breakpoints: {
        // 700px and up shoes 2 slides
        700: {
          slidesPerView: 2
        },
        // 1200px and up shoes 3 slides
        1200: {
            slidesPerView: 3
        }
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried overwriting the expiration time of the cookies, expiration so that they persist even after the user logs out. To do this, you can set the max-age attribute of the cookie to a specific number of seconds.